# WPF ComboBox PreviewKeyDown doesn't raise when pressing Up or Down Arrow keys

Tags: c#, wpf, events, keydown

I defined a combobox in the XAML as following

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbDate" Width="100" Height="20" IsEditable="True"
       PreviewKeyDown="CmbDate_PreviewKeyDown"></ComboBox>
```

I also defined a method that listens to PreviewKeyDown event in the code-behind as following

```
private void CmbDate_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        if(e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            if (sender is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
                cmb.Focus();
                cmb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }
}
```

But the PreviewKeyDown event never gets raised when I press Up or Down arrow keys.

PreviewKeyDown does get raised if I press Left or Right arrow key, though.
Is there any right way to achieve what I want?

Or is it the default behavior of combobox control and we have to cheat / hack?